# Как настроить WatchService (java)

Tags: java, файлы, файловая-система, nio2

Как настроить `WatchService`, чтобы можно было следить за изменениями в какой-то другой папке, а не только в `user.home` или `user.dir`?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.watchservice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;



public class DirectoryWatcherExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println("Event kind:" + event.kind() + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
            }
            key.reset();
        }

        watchService.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Укажите тут любую другую директорию `Paths.get("/somedirectory")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно изменить это:
`Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

На это:
`Path path = Paths.get("Ваша_желаемая_директория");`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]